# Why can I not get the length in itertool.product? Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-itertools, python-3.6, cartesian-product

I read the other post to get the length of `itertool.product()` however the OP's question was never answer. I don't understand why this len() error is occuring. Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import itertools

def function():
    rgb1 = [r,g,b]
    return itertools.product(rgb1, repeat=3)    #I added this

img = Image.open("anyImage.jpg")
r, g, b = img.split()

cartesianList = itertools.product([r,g,b], repeat=3)

for set in cartesianList:
    new_img = Image.merge("RGB", cartesianList)
    new_img.show()
```

Output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Trevor/PycharmProjects/Pillow Test/test3.py", line 14, in <module>
    new_img = Image.merge("RGB", cartesianList)
  File "C:\Users\Trevor\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2608, in merge
    if getmodebands(mode) != len(bands) or "*" in mode:
TypeError: object of type 'itertools.product' has no len()
```

Comment: `itertools.product` does not return a list. It returns an iterator, which does not support `len`.

Comment: Why are you merging `cartesianList`? What is `set` for?

Comment: You should turn your product returned value into list like: cartesianList= list(product(r, g, b))

Comment: You could have a product of infinite source iterators, which you really don't want to consume to find the length of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for set in cartesianList:
    new_img = Image.merge("RGB", cartesianList)
```

Pretty sure you meant `Image.merge("RGB", set)` here

---

longer answer for the sake of future visitors:

**Q:** Why can I not get the length of an itertools.product?
**A:** most itertools functions return generators, which don't have a length because they are lazily evaluated (and potentially infinite).

**Q:** Why do I get an itertools.product error when I pass `cartesianProduct` into the Image.merge?
**A:** PIL checks that you gave it 3 channels when you specify `Image.merge("RGB", [foo])`, so it calls `len(foo)`. While this works for each `set` in `cartesianList` obviously it doesn't work for `cartesianList`

Comment: This is exactly what I missed! Works great now